# Displaying items of a list in a text window

Tags: java, performance

In a game that I am making, I have a look in my game which goes through an array, and lists the things in the array

```
public void listOpen() {
    ArrayList<String> open = main.getOpenable();
    for(int i = 0; i < open.size(); i++) {
        String value = open.get(i);
        textWindow.append(value + "\n");
        error.setScroll();
    }
}
```

Sometimes when I'm running the program I notice that it lags slightly. Is there anyway I can make it more efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make only one `textWindow.append()` operation and consider using `StringBuilder`, to construct string to append.

```
public void listOpen() {
    ArrayList<String> open = main.getOpenable();
    StringBuilder appendBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < open.size(); i++) {
        String value = open.get(i);
        appendBuilder.append(value).append("\n");
        error.setScroll();
    }
    textWindow.append(appendBuilder.toString());
}
```

Comment: You can also pull out the setScroll call, if it's a UI call then only the last call will have an effect.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add a couple of points.

**Code to the Interface instead of its Implementation:**

When declaring an object you want to declare it as the highest level object needed as opposed to its specific implementation.

In this case you wrote:

```
ArrayList<String> open = main.getOpenable();
```

This requires that `main.getOpenable()` returns an `ArrayList`. What happens if in the future you decide to have it return a `LinkedList`? It could break the current code.

It is a much better idea to simply do:

```
List<String> open = main.getOpenable();
```

Now you can pass it any sort of `List` with no issues.

Note: Obviously you need to ensure that the interface contains all the methods you need to call, but here that is the case.

**You can use a for-each loop to iterate over the List:**

This may be a style choice, but it leads to cleaner code. Consider the following (using the `StringBuilder` effeciency):

```
public void listOpen() {
    ArrayList<String> open = main.getOpenable();
    StringBuilder appendBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String value : open) {
        appendBuilder.append(value).append("\n");
        error.setScroll();
    }
    textWindow.append(appendBuilder.toString());
}
```

Here the benefit is small, but it does remove a line of code and removes some of the possibility of errors.